# The distance is far too big between the text and marginal notes

Tags: notes, ledmac

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{ledmac}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart

A \ledsidenote{\textit{big car}}

\pend

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

The distance is huge between the text and the sidenote.

Comment: The side note is typeset in the right margin and this is how it's supposed to work. Can you tell more precisely what you mean?

Comment: The side note appears farther than the page number, which is odd.

Comment: should I use the marginnote package?

Comment: That would give exactly the same result. The marginal notes are in the margin, the page number isn't.

Comment: how could I make the side notes appear right next to the text?

Comment: The side notes are typeset at a distance `\marginparsep` from the right margin (outer margin in a two-sided context). This distance is, by default, 7pt with the class you're using. What do you mean by "right next to the text"?

Comment: The text is quite a thin column, which is why I want marginal notes but not in the margins.

Comment: Is it possible to annotate marginal notes with \edtext{blah}{\Afootnote{blah}}?

Comment: Either you want marginal notes (in the margin) or you want a different thing. It's quite useless to insist without making clear what precisely you want to achieve.

Comment: I apologize if I'm not clear enough. My text is quite a thin column and I want sidenotes for it, so I guess these are not marginal notes strictly speaking. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation, you can use

```
\ledlsnotesep=<length>
\ledrsnotesep=<length>
```

to change the distance between text and (respectively) the left and the right notes.

But as you can see if you use

```
\beginnumbering
\pstart

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id 
est laborum.  \ledsidenote{\textit{big car}}

\pend

\endnumbering
```

the page number is just next to the text right margin. So it's the line number which needs to be moved. You can use, for that, the package `fancyhdr`.

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to avoid issuing an error when `ledmac` is used without the `noeledmac` option? A warning seems better suited.

Comment: I think no one should start with ledmac today. So I prefer to produce an error, to be sure people knwo that ledmac is obsolete.

Comment: At least format the error message in a sensible way; now it's split across lines at random. My proposal: ``\ledmac@error{%
  Using package `ledmac' is deprecated. We suggest\MessageBreak
  using `eledmac' instead.  If you want to continue\MessageBreak
  with `ledmac', you can disable this message by\MessageBreak
  adding the option `noeledmac' when loading `ledmac'}{\@ehc}``

Comment: done https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/commit/f64bd50667dee7ed7649fd6b07e33c87879f8506